# What is the better way, keeping adapter as an inner class of activity or outside?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, adapter, listactivity

I want to check the better and faster way for program of using adapter for a ListView. Is it out or in activity class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is more of a Java question than Android.

Inner classes are more for making your code readable and do not affect performance **as long as you use static inner classes**. Static inner classes are pulled out by the compiler and compiled as separate classes (Class$InnerClass).

So if using inner classes are helpful to you in terms of code organization, you can safely go ahead and use them. Though I'd strongly recommend using static inner classes.

*Edit*

Static inner classes suffice in this context, which is of an adapter which wouldn't need access to any of the variables of the Activity.

Comment: +1, though worth noting that the advantage of using a static inner class is minor and if you need access to non-static fields from the enclosing class then a non-static inner class is appropriate.

Comment: @mikera I agree. My answer was more in the current context of an Adapter, edited my answer to include this