# Is it (or not) encouraged to use inner class in Android development?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

I read in some book that using inner class will make the app bigger(several KBs per inner class used), but is there any concern about the performance? I saw inner classes used in Google's sample code, but in general, is it encouraged to use inner class or not, in Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Inner classes are excellent when you want to implement an interface method more than 1 time and in more than 1 way in the same class.

**2.** Anonymous classes are the best way to create event handlers.

**3. Using top level classes (ie static inner class) will be light, as it moreover like an external class which is not having any implicit reference to the outer class.**

**4. Non-static inner class will be bit of overhead, as it holds implicit reference to the outer class.**

Eg:
       **For inner class having implict reference**

Eg:

```
    public class outer{

                int x = 10;


               class inner{

                 int x=5;

                 public void go(){

   System.out.println("Inner x: "+ this.x);           // Prints x in Inner class
   System.out.println("Inner x: "+ Outer.this.x);     // Prints x in Outer class


                }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any significant code size difference between inner classes, anonymous classes, and regular classes.  As to the difference between inner and regular, you can unzip your jar and see that a regular .class file is generated for each one.

So don't go nuts with unnecessary ones, but it's also not an "avoid at all costs" scenario either.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use static inner classes, you'll be fine. Static inner classes are more for arranging classes conveniently and for scoping them properly.

This is not the case with non-static inner classes as they hold a reference to the class that holds them. This is not only heavy, but dangerous too in Android, when the holding class is a live one i.e. has a Context attached to it. This can cause memory leaks, potentially leaking your entire application.

Here is a very similar question (regarding the user of inner classes for adapters in Activities) and the answer:
[What is the better way, keeping adapter as an inner class of activity or outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904038/what-is-the-better-way-keeping-adapter-as-an-inner-class-of-activity-or-outside/8904525#8904525)